# Запрет нажатия на checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, recycleview

Есть список RecycleView в каждом CardView есть CheckBox. При нажатии на CardView программно изменяю состояние CheckBox. Однако при нажатии на CheckBox происходит двойное нажатие. Как запретить изменение состояние CheckBox со стороны пользователя? Или есть другие способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте эти строчки к своему чекбоксу

`android:focusable="false"
 android:clickable="false"`